# Bootstrap dynamic input generation using jQuery "form-row" is not working

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

When i clicking Add Wings/Blocks button the dynamic fields will created with using jQuery, those are the BootStrap components.

**I want arrange a 3 fields from (left to right) in a single row**, I made code for that also, but **"form-row"** is not arranging the fields, normally it is working, but from the dynamic code only is not working, it is arranging the fields one below one.

Here is a sample image [image: This image link shows the form fields one below one]

Sample codes

```js
 var wrapper         = $("#addingInp"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $("#addButton"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 0; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-row">'
              +'<div class"form-group col-md-3">'
              +'<label for="block'+x+'">Block</label>'
              +'<input id="block'+x+'"  type="text" class="form-control block" placeholder="Enter Name" style="width:auto"/>'
              +'</div>'
              
              +'<div class"form-group col-md-4">'
              +'<label for="floor'+x+'">No of floors</label>'
              +'<input id="floorstart'+x+'"  type="text" class="form-control floor" placeholder="Start (Ex : A or 1)" style="width:auto"/>'
              +'<input id="floorend'+x+'"  type="text"  class="form-control flatend" placeholder="End (Ex : Z or 100)" style="width:auto"/>'
              +'</div>'
              
              +'<div class"form-group col-md-4">'
              +'<label for="flats'+x+'">No/Name of flats</label>'
              +'<input id="flatstart'+x+'"  type="text"  class="form-control flatstart" placeholder="Start (Ex : A or 1)" style="width:auto"/>'
              +'<input id="flatend'+x+'"  type="text"  class="form-control flatend" placeholder="End (Ex : Z or 100)" style="width:auto"/>'
              +'</div>' 
              
               +'<a href="#" class="remove_field col-md-1"> X </a>'
              +'</div> '); //add input box
            x++; //text box increment now x=1 after x++ x=2,so next code 2%2==0 is true
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
```

```html
<div style="margin-left: 4px;" class="form-group col-md-12">
    <input type='button' class="btn-primary form-control" value='Add Wings/Blocks' id='addButton' style="width:auto" />
</div>

<div id="addingInp" class="form-row col-md-12">
</div>
```

Comment: what is problem @vignesh R

Comment: in that image shown i marked ,that is dynamic codes,i need to arrange it in single row not one after one,right now it is one below one generating..which means bootstrap "class="form-row" " is not working

Comment: you have missed `=` sign in class jquery part

Comment: where in jquery ji?i can't find..pls mention the correct code

Comment: its working copy https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/gXybrO

Comment: you have missed `).append('<div class="form-row">'
              +'<div class"form-group col-md-3">'` in this `=` sign is missing

Comment: really thank you ji...it is working..

Comment: neengale ans post pannirunga ji...andha linkaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed the `=`  sign in your append() method

```
 $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-row">'
                +'<div class="form-group col-md-3">'
                +'<label for="block'+x+'">Block</label>'
                +'<input id="block'+x+'"  type="text" class="form-control block" placeholder="Enter Name" style="width:auto"/>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div class="form-group col-md-4">'
                +'<label for="floor'+x+'">No of floors</label>'
                +'<input id="floorstart'+x+'"  type="text" class="form-control floor" placeholder="Start (Ex : A or 1)" style="width:auto"/>'
                +'<input id="floorend'+x+'"  type="text"  class="form-control flatend" placeholder="End (Ex : Z or 100)" style="width:auto"/>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div class="form-group col-md-4">'
                +'<label for="flats'+x+'">No/Name of flats</label>'
                +'<input id="flatstart'+x+'"  type="text"  class="form-control flatstart" placeholder="Start (Ex : A or 1)" style="width:auto"/>'
                +'<input id="flatend'+x+'"  type="text"  class="form-control flatend" placeholder="End (Ex : Z or 100)" style="width:auto"/>'
                +'</div>' 

                    +'<a href="#" class="remove_field col-md-1"> X </a>'
                +'</div> ');
```